github actions workflow_run not triggering, child action stuck in `Expected — Waiting for status to be reported state`
I have below workflow:
name: w1

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  run_w1:
    runs-on:
      labels: depot-ubuntu-22.04-8
      group: public-depot
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      (...)

This workflow was committed to main on our repository, as I understand it won't trigger other workflows unless it is on main.
I already had some other workflows that I wanted to modify so they are executed only if the w1 is successful. These workflows are already specified in branch protection rules. They were originally executed on pull_request and push, in new branch I changed them to be executed on workflow_run like below:
name: UNIT TESTS

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [w1]
    types: [completed]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == "success" }}
    runs-on:
      labels: depot-ubuntu-22.04-4
      group: public-depot
    timeout-minutes: 10
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
    steps:
      (...)

When I push to branch, the w1 workflow executes and results in success, however UNIT TESTS workflow (which, as I understand, should be triggered upon completion of w1 workflow) is never triggered (it sits in Expected — Waiting for status to be reported state). I have gone through documentation and also found this question in github discussions, this question on SO and I think I have setup everything correctly, but it seems I'm missing something, would appreciate any hints.
